# Restoring a Azure web app backup into different web app service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-cli

I would like to restore a azure web app into another web app (basically cloning a web app) which was backed up into a storage account. To do so, I use the following command:

```
az appservice web config backup restore --backup-name backup-clone5 --container-url "SAS-URL" --resource-group resource-us --webapp-name origin-app-name --target-name target-app-name
```

When I run the above command I get the following error:

```
Website with given name origin-app-name already exists.
------------------------------------------------------------
```

From the above error message I understood, that azure is trying to restore the app with the name that's provided in the parameter `--webapp-name` and ignores the `--target-name` parameter.

So I thought of entering the above command again with the `--webapp-name` parameter as something that doesn't exist:

```
az appservice web config backup restore --backup-name backup-clone5 --container-url "SAS-URL" --resource-group resource-us --webapp-name new-app-name --target-name target-app-name
```

But guess what azure is complaining now:

```
The Resource 'Microsoft.Web/sites/new-app-name' under resource group 'resource-us' was not found.
------------------------------------------------------------
```

So the confusion here is what is azure CLI expecting the value of `--webapp-name` parameter to be? and what is `--target-name` ? Is `--webapp-name` the name of the original web app name that was backed up? If so why am I getting the error: `Website with given name origin-app-name already exists.` Unfortunately Azure's documentation is worse than bad and it gives no insight on these whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I figured it out. The following is the correct structure of the command:

```
az appservice web config backup restore --backup-name backup-clone5 --container-url "SAS-URL" --resource-group resource-us --webapp-name destination-app-name --overwrite
```

--webapp-name is the app name when you would like the backup to be restored and not the origin app name. Still the purpose of parameter --target-app-name is a big black box.